# How to pickpocket in Assassins Creed 1 on Xbox?

Tags: assassins-creed

Once you lock on to your target with LT how do you actually pickpocket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you lock on to your target get very close behind them without them staring at you. When you're within arms reach, the right button (Circle on the PS3, Ⓑ/B on the 360, and Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> on the PC) should change from "Gentle Push" to "Pickpocket". Pushing the Pickpocket button should steal the item from the person and complete the mission if the target isn't looking when you do it.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. The traget will turn on me and push me away, calling for guards.
Does it need to walk or stand? In the description in the german version its stated that the target needs to stand and not walk. Is this right?

Comment: @SebastianP.R.Gingter It should work when they're walking too. I think your problem is that they're seeing you. You have to do it when they aren't looking towards you.

Comment: Do you click the right button or click and hold the button?